# Is it possible to modify an object(time series) in a model?

Tags: r, list

I implement a list object in R. Is it possible to re-assign an object inside this list?
The object I have to re-assign is a time-series.

```
forecast_list <- list(
  model = NULL,
  method = "LSTM",
  mean = forcasted,
  x = kt,
  fitted = predicted_total,
)
```

HerecI would like to do:

```
forecast_list$mean = time_series
```